# Sybase query for multiple foreign key pointing to a single primary key

Tags: sybase

I have 2 tables Currencies and pairs with following fields,

**Currencies**

- Currencies_ShortName
- Currencies_Id (Primary Key)

**Pairs**

- Pairs_ShortName
- Currencies_Id_1 Reference (Currencies)Currencies_Id
- Currencies_Id_2 Reference (Currencies)Currencies_Id

I want to display Pairs_ShortName, Currencies_Id_1 & Currencies_Id_2 with Currencies_ShortName.

I tried
`Select a.Pairs_ShortName, a.Currencies_Id_1, a.Currencies_Id_2, b.Currencies_ShortName from Pairs a, Currencies b where a.Currencies_Id_1 = .Currencies_Id`

but it only displays Pairs_ShortName, Currencies_Id_1, Currencies_ShortName.

I want to display Pairs_ShortName, Currencies_Id_1, Currencies_ShortName, Currencies_Id_2, Currencies_ShortName

Comment: Why do you have two currency id foreign keys in your Pairs table. What are you trying to achive here ? Do you have a primary key on your Pairs table ?   You are missing your 'b' prefix i.e. b.Currencies_Id in your where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Check below Query,

select
 p.Pairs_ShortName, p.Currencies_Id_1, c1.Currencies_ShortName1, p.Currencies_Id_2, c.Currencies_ShortName2
from 
Pairs p,Currencies c1,Currencies c2
where p.Currencies_Id_1 =c1.Currencies_Id
and  p.Currencies_Id_2= c2.Currencies_Id

Thanks..